# Error enumerating empty folder using Office365 API in OneDrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint, office365

In the last couple of days I'm experiencing a strange problem with the Office365 API when I try to enumerate the children of an empty folder in OneDrive for Business. It happens both using the latest libraries and when I directly call the REST API:

```
GET {personal-site-url}/_api/v1.0/Files/{folder-id}/children
```

If the specified folder has no files and sub-folders in it the call returns with the following error:

> `{error: {code: "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",message: "loginNameToIdMap Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the loginNameToIdMap parameter."}}`

Last week the request still worked fine, returning no items for empty folders, but without error. I think this is a critical bug in the system that was introduced lately. I've tried with two separate Office365 subscriptions and the problem can be reproduced in both.

Is this behavior by design or is it really a bug, and is anybody else also experiencing this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a possible bug in a commercial web service and not programming

Comment: @Paul How is that not programming?

Comment: Just because the OP's program results in the error does not make it about programming. I can think of no useful answer that could possibly be contributed by the Stackoverflow community). We can't answer if it's by design or if it's a bug and finding an off site resource is off topic anyway.

Comment: I also believe that this question still can be related to programming. Maybe my wording wasn't the best, English is not my native language. After all We are talking about API, which methods can be called in different ways. Maybe the specific method I'm calling shouldn't be called in this specific case.

Comment: @DavidWeisz, OK, well, that's a different question. Does it work with non-empty folders? The error message looks related to authentication - have you changed how do you do that recently?

Comment: For non empty folders it works perfectly and all the other API calls are also working so there is not problem with the authentication. I didn't changed anything in the code lately. For the same code that was checked in to our source control the unit testing just started to fail, together with our production application. Meantime I'm implementing a workaround asking for the child count of the folder prior to asking for its list of children. Not the perfect solution but it works. I hope that some insiders from Microsoft are also reading this post and can give a definitive answer.